# System.Data.ConstraintException: Column 'ID' is constrained to be unique. Value '6' is already present

Tags: .net, vb.net

VS2022 PRO
VB WinForm App
.net 4.7.2

I have a simple combobox (Status).  When the selected value is changed, a readonly datagridview is update from an SQL tableadapter.  Tableadapter is set to "ClearBeforeFill" by default.

Applying a filter to the bindingsource after selection is changed.
Process works fine until I select a status for which there are no records.  Rather than simply returning no records I get this error "System.Data.ConstraintException: Column 'ID' is constrained to be unique.  Value '6' is already present".  Value changes, of course, if I have selected another status for which there are no records.

I even added a bindingsource.RemoveFilter before applying the filter to clear the filter.
It's behaving as if the tableadapter is not clearing before each 'refresh'.  I can't figure out any other component that might be trying to add records thus encountering a unique constraint.

```
Me.VwConsumerProvidersAllTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsConsProv.vwConsumerProvidersAll)
Me.VwConsumerProvidersAllBindingSource.RemoveFilter()
<<< modify filter string >>>
Me.VwConsumerProvidersAllBindingSource.Filter = FilterString
```

The error occurs after the filter step.

I've read just about every other community posting for this error, but none seem to be the same conditions.

As per one thread, I did change the dataset property of "EnforceConstraints=False", but that had no effect.  Changed that back to the default of 'true'.

I just started using VS2022 PRO .net 4.7.2.  Previously I was using VS2019 .net 4.6.1 and have never had this issue before.

Answer (score 0):

All this trouble just because I inadvertently set the "Selected Value" in the toolbox tasks data binding mode settings!  Aargh!

The selected value field should be left blank.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).